# What is mass constituted by quarks in a proton?

Tags: mass, standard-model, mass-energy, quarks, protons

In a question I read [Quarks in a hadron: where does the mass come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207644/)

"The sum of the masses of the quarks in a proton is approximately $30~\text{MeV}/c^2$, whereas the mass of a proton is $931~\text{MeV}/c^2$. "

Is it correct, since a proton has zillions of *partons*.

Mass contributed by valence quarks is ~8-9MeV.
Is OP correct about 30MeV.

Comment: I am not sure why you would consider a proton to have "zillions of mesons"

Comment: You cannot simply add the quark masses. The binding energy that holds them together manifests itself as a significant portion of the proton's mass.

Comment: @Jaywalker  http://cosmologyscience.com/cosblog/three-quarks-dont-add-up-to-one-proton-not-even-close/

Comment: @Jaywaker I know about binding energy and stuff.

Comment: Ok I believe what is going on here is that a number of mathematical corrections in the possible interactions of quarks ends up constituting the mass of the proton. You may consider reading QED The Strange Theory of Light and Matter by Richard Feynman as these types of corrections are explained albeit in the case of electromagnetic interactions and not for Quantum Chromo dynamics.

Comment: @Jaywalker Feynman for class 12? Really!!!

Comment: Its an easy read! I really enjoyed it. The book is based on a public lecture Feynmen held for non physicists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35900/discussion-between-anubhav-goel-and-jaywalker).

Comment: If you already "know about binding energy" then what's the problem?

Comment: @lemon I want to know approx mass contributed by quarks and gluon's seperately. And if its not possible to find it, then what is 30 MeV here.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-gluon-binding-energy-for-protons-and-neutrons-in-laymans-terms

Comment: @lemon Is Statement in question correct or false then?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235374/estimating-the-characteristic-energy-of-the-neutron/235723#235723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The quark mass contribution to the mass of the proton can be determined in lattice QCD. The result is indeed about 30 MeV. More accurately, $\Delta M_p=37\pm 8\pm 6$ MeV, see [Nucleon mass and sigma term from lattice QCD with two light fermion flavors](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.7034).
2. This quantity is sometimes called the nucleon sigma term, and chiral symmetry implies that it is related to pion-nucleon scattering. This leads to independent determinations of $\Delta M_p$ (which, historically, precede the lattice results). These days, the results are consistent with lattice QCD.
3. Note that
   $$
   \Delta M_p = \langle p|\sum_f m_f \bar\psi_f\psi_f |p\rangle
   $$
   where $f$ labels quark flavor ($f$=up,down,..) and $m_f$ are quark masses. In a non-relativistic quark model we would assume that $\langle p|\bar{u}u|p\rangle=2$ and  $\langle p|\bar{d}d|p\rangle=1$, and that $\Delta M_p=2m_u+m_d$.
4. This estimate is not right, for several reasons. Neither $m_f$ nor $\bar\psi_f\psi$ are renormalization group invariants, only the product is.
   Also, computed at a "reasonable" renormalization scale, the sum $2m_u+m_d$ is smaller than $\Delta M_p$. Roughly, there are more than three quarks in a proton (there are several quark-anti-quark pairs).
5. The number of quark-anti-quark pairs, or equivalently the number of mesons, is not sharply defined. Only $\Delta M_p$ is. Taking some phenomenologically reasonable cutoff to estimate the number gives values of a few, not "zillions".

Comment: I had spent 6 hours realising OP was wrong.I accepted an answer. I commented on OPs question. He too changed it. Now, you are saying he was correct.

Comment: At least explain in layman's term.

Comment: Does few means 3~4 appx.

Comment: 1) Yes, the 30 MeV figure is correct. 2) 3-4 pairs is a reasonable number. This is what you get if you combine the 37 MeV, with the MS-bar quark masses 2.2 and 4.8 quoted by fermion (I have not checked, but these numbers sound reasonable).

Comment: So, are these 2~3 new mesons , a part of patrons?

Comment: Partons, not patrons. Yes in deep inelastic scattering these pairs are seen as partons.

Comment: What is physical significance of nucleon sigma term?

Comment: It is the difference in the mass of the proton in our world, where the Higgs field has an expectation value (vev) and quarks are massive, and an imaginary world in which the Higgs vev is zero and quarks are massless.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called the *parton distribution function* for the proton. It roughly describes the energy/momentum shared by the partons (quarks and gluons) inside a proton (or any other hadron, of course). It is deduced from experiments according to theoretical guidelines, and must be defined in reference to the energies involved in the experiment. You'll find more info on the web. Below, you can see the parton distribution functions for u, d, s, c quarks, their antiquarks and gluons, @ 4 GeV (the image is taken from Peskin and Schroeder's *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*, sec. 17.4, fig. 17.6). Beware of the plotted function ( $xf(x)$ instead of $f(x)$ ).

[image]

P.S.: It is not correct, protons do not contain zillions of mesons. Nuclei may contain them, but not hadrons.

Comment: Please read my edit.

Comment: I did. It says that they're made up of zillions of partons, not mesons. Hence, my answer.

Comment: And no, it doesn't add up to 30 MeV, but you should be made aware of the fact that the mass of a quark is not a well defined concept, at least not in the sense to which you may be used to (e.g. in the sense of the mass of an electron).

Comment: I think what the question is asking about is the nucleon sigma term, which is indeed about 30 MeV. There are mesons (quark-anti-quark pairs) in the proton, but the number is not well defined (there is no RG invariant operator that corresponds to it),

Answer (score 0):

The quark masses are not uniquely defined, they can be given in an $\bar{MS}(2GeV)$ scheme as $m_u \sim 2.2 MeV$, $m_d \sim 4.8 MeV$. The rest mass of a nucleon comes from dominantly the strong interaction that binds the whole nucleon together. (Only a tiny fraction of mass comes from the electromagnetic interactions and through the Higgs mechanism.) The precise determination of nucleon masses can be achieved by ab initio lattice calculations.

Comment: That's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

The net mass-energy of bare quarks is a miniscule fraction of the bound system. A key fact to be noticed is that the force due to strong interaction does not decrease with increasing distance as in the case of electromagnetism. Another fact is that Heisenberg uncertainity is there.

Now we have a bound state of three quarks. For an easy comparision with electromagnetism, lets take a bound state of two quarks at first and later on we can move onto the case of three quarks.

So firstly, if two unlike charges are bounded by electromagnetism, then the coupling between them is less and falls down as inverse square with distance. As a result, for a system bounded by electromagnetism like the hydrogen atom, the distance is of the order of $10^{-10} m$ and there is no appreciable correction to the net mass of the the system as compared to the proton. {This depends on the magnitude of the charge too and is only a representative example}

Now if we take 2 quarks, then since the attractive force increases with distance, they form a bound system having a very small radius (Of the order of 1 fermi). Now Heisenberg uncertainity says that

$$\Delta x \Delta p \approx \hbar$$

Putting the values you can see that the quarks have a momentum uncertainity in the relativistic regime and have speeds close to light. This gives rise to extra mass of the quarks inside the bound state and is called the constituent quark mass.

Now finally we put 3 quarks in the system and get the proton. We can easily see that in order to hold these quarks together, we require that the potential energy should be greater than their kinetic energy. The potential energy in this case is provided by the gluon field, which gives rise to the remaining extra mass of the proton. Thus the proton is more heavy than the sum of individual quark masses.

Comment: Valence quark mass sum to 9MeV appx. . So, is statement about 30MeV wrong then?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel If you sum up bare quarks masses then they come out to be something like $9.4 \pm 1.9$ MeV..Nowhere near 30 MeV...But that part is not important.. What's important is that a huge amount of proton's mass is not composed of bare quark's mass.

Comment: What about zillions of quark-antiquark pairs here http://cosmologyscience.com/cosblog/three-quarks-dont-add-up-to-one-proton-not-even-close/

Comment: the gluon field acts on the quarks and results in creation of bound states called mesons, which are the carriers of strong force.. however exact details regarding mesons are not calculable from $QCD$ although they can be described to a good extent by chiral symmetry breaking..So basically they arise due to reaons given in the answer..

Comment: Then? Did you saw picture of proton?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel A meson is a bound state of a quark and anti-quark..As for the creation of quark-antiquark pairs, they are the effects of pair production, and occur in any quantum field theory..Since the strong force is described by a QFT, therefore they are gonna be there since QCD is a QFT..